Linear Regression Function in R with a Constrained (ie Bounded) variable and Binary Variables
I am running a linear regression with 3 independent variables of which 2 are continuous and one is binary representing a holiday. In 7th grade language it would look like
log(Unit_Sales) ~ Intercept + log(Unit_Price) + Log(Unit_Distribution) + Holiday (Binary Variable)
If I run a simple lm regression I get a tight model fit, but the Unit_Distribution Coefficient is above 1 and I need to force it to be less than 1 for a variety of reasons, that I would be happy to expand on.
The full model has more variables than the ones listed above that have pushed the 'Unit Distribution' coefficient down, but it remains above one. Rather than adding more variables to the model I want to force the Distribution Coefficient to be less than 1.
I tried using the 'optim' function to optimize my model with the constraints on Distribution to be less than 1. I had success with this approach when I excluded the Holiday (Binary Variable), but per my research I learned that 'optim' does not work with binary variables.
I tried'Rglpk_solve_LP' and am getting similar errors. Likely because I am not correctly writing out the constraint, rhs or upper and lower bounds matrixes.
How would you handle this problem? Is there a better package or function that I could use? Can you share the correct syntax for dealing with mixed variables with the Rglpk_solve_LP function or any other solution?

Would optim work if you coded Holiday as a numeric value (0/1)?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

replying to Eonema, unfortunately the optim function treats numeric values for dummy variables as a continuous variable which results in so funky results. The simple lm function seems to automatically understand if a variable that is coded as continuous but is just 0 and 1 is a binary variable and treats it correctly. optim does not

I found a work around this problem by
Step 1. run a simple lm regression to read the coefficients that impact the binary variables.
Single_Model <- lm(log(Units) ~ log(Distribution)  + log(Price)+ Dummy1 + log(Vibes) + log(Benefits) + Dummy2 + Dummy3 + Dummy4, data = Single_SBG)
Step 2. run the optim function on adjusted Units, where Adjusted Units = log(units)-Coef1Dummy1 - Coef2Dummy2 - Coeff3Dummy3 - Coef4Dummy4
Happy to share the full code if people are interested in the solution. Was a touch long, but got me to what I needed
